# Redirection in react-native if user is logged in. Avoid page flickering

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

In my react native app, I want to check if the user is logged in, then redirect it to dashboard else redirect to login page.
It is working however before redirecting to dashboard, it shows the login page for a brief moment. I want to avoid this screen flickering and send the user to the dashboard without showing the login page at all.
 I am using ComponentWillMOunt as below in login.js

```
componentWillMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('session', (err, session) => {
            console.log(session);
            if (session == 'ok') {

                this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'DashboardTab' })
                    ]
                }))

            }
        })
    }


This is my App.js for the nav-




const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
  Profile: { screen:ProfileScreen },
  Wallets: { screen:WalletsScreen },
  DashboardAccept: { screen:DashboardAccept },
  TermsConditions: { screen:TermsConditionsScreen },
  DashboardTab: { screen:DashboardTabScreen },
});
export default App;
```

Please help

Comment: I think this is because you are using the AsyncStorage and it needs a little bit of time to access it. I would suggest you add a loader on the login screen so the user doesn't see the flickering.

Comment: I was also having the same feeling, but for the time being, I have introduced a blank page at the start of the app that checks for the session values and then it navigated accordingly. Also, I want to introduce an image on the loading of the app, can you tell me how can I do it on the App.js page?

Comment: @moritzw ... can you help me to understand how to use splash screen in android/ios .....